# How mongodb indexing reduces the the number of docs to be scanned?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes

I have a collection like: `[{a: 'eXeD9', b: 399}, {a: 'eXe9', b: 35399} , xOBJs]`.

I am gonna search **24823293** in `b field`. So as I know I am have to traverse `all docs`, until there is a **match** with **24823293**.

So I am confused if I create an index for `b field`, how it can reduces the number of docs for scanning?

Because maybe the **24823293** is not within those `reduced docs`.

As I am a mobile application developer, I am confused here any help.

Answer (score 1):

Because with an index the scan will be performed against the possible **values** of `{ b }` (which would be stored in a time efficient data structure, like a B-tree) rather than on your whole set of documents.

Creating an index on `{ b }` can be seen as making the value of `{ b }` an access key to the documents themselves.

You end up with an index scan instead of a full scan, which can dramatically make the difference.

Comment: Thank you, you mean if we dont have an index. then the scan will aplly on `a field` too ?

Comment: the scan would apply on the whole set of documents, with a lookup on the b field in order to verify your query predicate

Comment: Thank you very much, if I search by `b field` will it be helpful to create index ?, because I use `$or: [{b: 'v1'}, {b: 'v2'}, {b: 'v3'}, xxx]` query and you know I have an array of objects to be compared with collection objects, so will it be still helpful to create index ?

Comment: absolutely. actally mongod even provides a notablescan option to make sure none of your queries makes its way to production without using an index https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/parameters/#param.notablescan

Comment: and one more question please, do we need to create index at any time (`insert, update, delete`) or just one time we create the index for a field?

Comment: just create the index that feats your need once, the database will use it whenever this is relevant